# In square Is there a way to automatically print orders in the receipt printer of my client?

Tags: android, square-connect

I'm building a native android app to sale pickup products of my client but the orders should be automatically printed in the Receipt printer of my client I want to know is this possible?

Currently I'm trying to use the "In-App Payments SDK", "orders API" and "payment API" to process the orders and payments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Square Orders API Pickup Order is a type of fulfillment order that can track delivery details and can track the status of whether the order has been picked up. Additionally you can configure your Square app to automatically print incoming orders by enabling "Automatically Print New Orders" in the Settings section of the Square app under "Remote Orders."